# Using jQuery for Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerpoint, effects

Ok - have been tasked with possibly an impossible (*or at least a potentially nightmarish*) scenario.

Need to come as close as possible to reproducing PowerPoint-like effects via HTML/JavaScript (*the spec is large and ugly, so I will spare you the details*).

Ultimately, I am looking for a solid launching point. I have used both **Prototype/Scriptaculous** as well as **jQuery** in many projects, and based on what I am seeing, it appears jQuery has the more plug-in available, so am leaning towards using jQuery.

Can anyone point me to some plug-ins, articles, or anything else that would help me in accelerating the research on this so I can define to my client what can and cannot be done.

Any other suggestions from you jQuery gurus are welcome of course.

Thanks -

Comment: What power-point like effects? And, from which version/release of PowerPoint are you basing your effects from? There are many!

Comment: Well, as I look at the spec (its really long), it looks like they listed them all (I see dozens of them). So for purposes of this question, lets just say 'as many as possible', and therefore, looking for a really strong plugin/framework that gets me closest as my starting point. Thanks -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "PowerPoint-like" effects. If you mean animations between slides you should look into

- the [Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) available with the standard jQuery download (fadeIn, fadeOut, slideDown, slideUp, ...)
- the [jQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) plugin
- the [jQuery Cycle plugins effects browser](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/browser.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) as well, which adds a number of effects.  [See here for a current list](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods).  Click on the link for each to see several demos, there are quite a few options for some that are powerpoint-ish.

For example, [try the various options in the dropdown here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation is very good:
[jQuery animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

However, if you are trying to achieve very complex effects you will almost certainly benefit from using a different framework. jQuery is a fantastic tool - particularly with the DOM, but animation isn't its strongpoint.

MooTools has a particularly good animation library (MooTools began life as a JavaScript animation framework) with a number of core modules that give you flexible tools to create complex animation chains yourself as well as a number of official and community-provided plugins. My recommendation would be to at least have a look at that first. You can certainly achieve this in jQuery but you will be making it more difficult for yourself!

- [MooTools homepage](http://mootools.net/)
- [Mootools Core Documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core)

Comment: I've dealt with both, I find the exact opposite to be true...personal preference maybe, but I found the MooTools approach lacking and verbose in many cases, **especially** when chaining, I'd love to see an example where chaining is easier *or* more concise.

Answer (score 0):

My $0.02: If you're doing complex effects, you need the library that runs the fastest, not the library that is the easiest to work with.